# c# passing arraylist from client side to server side via WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, arraylist

I'm using c#/.net 3.5. First time using WCF, I have 2 projects the back end WCF project:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICalculationService
    {

    [OperationContract]
    Int32 add(ArrayList arr);

    [OperationContract]
    Int32 mean(ArrayList arr);

}
```

}

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    public class CalculationService : ICalculationService
    {

  public Int32 add(ArrayList arr)
        {
            Int32 total = 0;
            Int32 sum = Convert.ToInt32(arr);
            foreach (int i in arr)
            {
                total += i;
            }

            return total;
        }

        public Int32 mean(ArrayList arr)
        {
            Int32 total = 0;
            foreach (int i in arr) 
            {
                total += i;
            }
            total = total / arr.Count;
            return total;
        }

    }
}
```

This back end does simple mathematical calculations, the values are generated on the front end.

and the front end GUI (Windows Forms Application).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        List<Int32> Mylist = new List<Int32>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   //Generating the Arraylist

            string lista = txtArray.Text;
            string[] array = lista.Split(',');

            int length = array.Length;

            for(int i=0; i< length; i++)
            {
                Int32 value = Convert.ToInt32(arr[i]);
                Mylist .Add(value);
                result.Text += arr[i];
            }

        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalculationServiceClient client = new CalculationServiceClient();
            Int32 result = client.add(arr);

        }

    }
}
```

The first button click generates an ArrayList using comma seperated values. The 2nd button click is supposed to call the method from the server side.

I recieve an error on the last line Int32 result = client.add(arr); Error being 'Can't convert type Arraylist to type object[]' I've tried using Generics, I get the same problem.

Comment: Does this compile: `Int32 sum = Convert.ToInt32(arr);`. Given that `ArrayList` does not implement `IConvertible`?

Comment: After adding the collectiontype on the service reference it seems to work fine. It's doing the calculations back end and displaying it on the front end

Comment: Sorry Lews Therin, That does not compile, I got rid of it it wasnt needed. Great catch :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When generating the Service reference, you should set the CollectionType to System.Collections.Arraylist - it's in the advanced section in the UI. It defaults to passing arrays.

There's more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850(v=vs.90).aspx